# copyToClipboard func only copying TextField labels, not values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, clipboard

I'm trying to create a copyToClipboard function that grabs the values from TextFields on a page and copies those values when the Copy button is selected. Here is the function:

```js
function copyToClipboard() {
    const textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.innerText = "";
    const parentElement = document.getElementById("span");

    if (parentElement) {
      textArea.value = parentElement.innerText;
      document.body.appendChild(textArea);
      textArea.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      textArea.remove();
    }
  }
```

And here are my TextFields:

```js
<Grid id="span" container spacing={8}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Last Pulled"
            value={formatTimestamp(r.createdAt, "MM/DD/YYYY")}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true
            }}
            className="text"
          />

          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Credit History Length(months)"
            value={creditHistLength}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true
            }}
          />
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="SSN Match Indicator"
            value={r.ssnMatch}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true
            }}
            className="text"
          />
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Date of Birth"
            value={formatTimestamp(r.dateOfBirth, "MM/DD/YYYY")}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true
            }}
            className="text"
          />

          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="FICO"
            value={r.fico}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true
            }}
          />
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Monthly Mortgage Payment"
            value={mortgagePayment}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true
            }}
          />
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Disputed?"
            value={r.isDisputed ? "YES" : "NO"}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true
            }}
          />
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Hit Indicator"
            value={r.hitIndicator}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true
            }}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

And here is the button:

```js
   <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={copyToClipboard}>
        <FileCopy />
        &nbsp;copy to clipboard
   </Button>
```

Right now, the copyToClipboard function is only selecting and copying the labels of each TextField, instead of selecting the values of each TextField. Ideally, it would grab both the labels and the values, but I'll settle for a solution that grabs only the values.

Comment: when you do this `textArea.value = parentElement.innerText;`  you only select the innerhtml and not what's inside the textarea...to make this work one solution i could think of is give all your textareas a same class. Then select all the elements using document.getElementsByClassName..Now you can loop over them and store the value of each textarea in a single string by concatenating them and then you can call ` textArea.value = {yoursinglestring};`

Comment: @KaranGarg thanks, Karan! your suggestion put me on the right track, but I am still only pulling the TextField labels when I loop through the TextFields like so:       `let resultString = "";
    for (const i in textFieldsArray) {
      if (textFieldsArray.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        resultString += textFieldsArray[i].textContent;
      }
    }
    textArea.value = resultString;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    textArea.remove();
  } `

Comment: Can you try using `value` instead of `textContent`

Comment: never mind, I figured it out. I decided to use `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` and then changed it to `resultString += textFieldsArray[I].defaultValue`. thanks for your help!

Comment: Great. It worked for you.